# com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: Unauthenticated

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a GKE cluster where my application is running. My application is built using springboot.  And I have google Datastore database which is running in a separate GCP Project.
It throws the error "DatastoreException: Unauthenticated" when it tries to connect to datastore database during application start-up.

The connection happens through "Service account" permissions, application service account having necessary(Datastore user) permission to the datastore database. But it still fails.

Below two are the similar scenarios where it works:
1.
With similar set-up in a lower environment, it works.

2.
I have another application running inside same GKE cluster which is using the same service account but connecting to another datastore database with similar role to the service account, it works fine here.

Comment: What do you mean with "similar set-up in a lower environment"? Also, does the other app in the GKE cluster connect to the same Datastore DB? I mean, both apps in GKE are in one GCP project, and Datastore is in a different GCP project, right?